# Using DB2 column alias within same select

Tags: sql, db2

I have a working query but I'm trying to use the column aliases in order to create more calculations in my select and it says the column can't be found (i.e. it can't use the alias).

For instance, the working query:

```
select employee,
       sum(case when date_field between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' and category = 'CategoryOne' then salesprice else 0 end) as priorDate,
       sum(case when date_field between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' then salesprice else 0  end) as priorTotal,
       cast(Round((DEC(sum(case when date_field between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' and category = 'CategoryOne' then salesprice else 0 end),12,2)/sum(case when date_field between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' then salesprice else 0  end)) * 100,2) as decimal(12,2)) as priorPercent,
       sum(case when date_field between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and category = 'CategoryOne' then salesprice else 0 end) as currentDate,
       sum(case when date_field between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' then salesprice else 0 end) as currentSales,
       cast(Round((DEC(sum(case when date_field between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and category = 'CategoryOne' then salesprice else 0 end),12,2)/sum(case when date_field between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' then salesprice else 0  end)) * 100,2) as decimal(12,2)) as currentPercent
from table
group by employee;
```

But for my two percentages (the two rows that start with cast) I've tried using just `priorDate / priorTotal` but it won't work and so I have to repeat the 2 whole calculations as a percentage.

I want to also obtain a difference in percentages which would be much easier to declare by using the aliases, and maybe more performant?

Comment: "more performant" -- Usually not. Just because an expression occurs twice in a query doesn't mean it's evaluated twice. After all SQL is declarative not imperative and the optimizer usually catches such things.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured but I wasn't positive. Is there a way to use the aliases for clarity and cleaning it up though?

Comment: @TomN. Usually you'd just evaluate the expressions you want to reuse in a subquery or CTE with aliases, then you can refer to the aliases in the outer query.

Comment: You cannot use aliases that way. You could use a CTE (`WITH` clause) but I'm not sure if DB2 supports that. Or query a subquery with the base calculations in it. But there's a chance, that the optimizer cannot handle that and this gets less performant. A chance, it's not necessarily the case. But the safest bet is to repeat the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this using a CTE/subquery:

```
with t as (
      select employee,
             sum(case when date_field between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' and category = 'CategoryOne' then salesprice else 0 end) as priorDate,
             sum(case when date_field between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-31' then salesprice else 0  end) as priorTotal,
             sum(case when date_field between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and category = 'CategoryOne' then salesprice else 0 end) as currentDate,
             sum(case when date_field between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' then salesprice else 0 end) as currentSales,
      from table
      group by employee
     )
select t.*,
       round(t.priorDate * 100.0 / nullif(t.priorTotal, 0), 2) as priorPercent,
       round(t.priorTotal * 100.0 / nullif(t.currentTotal, 0), 2) as currentPercent
from t;
```

Comment: That's more what I was looking for, thank you! If I wanted to set something with ```currentPercent - priorPercent``` I still wouldn't be able to use those aliases in the final select though, right? I'd have to set them in another subselect?

Comment: @TomN. . . . Exactly.  Or you would use the expressions themselves.